# Is there any action/filter hook to use when an image gets edited in the editor?

Tags: images, filters, editor, actions, updates

I can't find a specific hook. If I already have added an image to an article via editor and then I edit it, I'd like to intercept the code just before it is  sent again to the editor.

I already use 'image_send_to_editor' but it works on the first image insertion, not if the image gets edited.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you find such filter? Looking for it too.

Comment: mmm to be true, I didn't remember :P 4 years are too much for me :) But I think the answers below can be interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

**edit_attachment** 
Runs when an attached file is edited/updated to the database. Action function arguments: attachment ID

This is found deocumented in the Codex under the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29). Please take a closer look at the Codex before posting questions related directly to syntax. :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Great description.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also be surprised to find that the straightforward answer of using `the_content` will work, too.

For instance, I wrote an answer to a question on this site that asked how to add a class to the anchor tag on linked images. In some cases, such as when the image is edited after being added, solutions that use `image_send_to_editor` won't work. You might want to check it out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189881/67366